# Как можно отследить в одном потоке то, что другой поток использовал метод объекта, над которым они вместе работают?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я делаю лабораторную работу по многопоточности и испытываю трудности.

Есть склад – очередь, и три потока – один производитель и два потребителя. Производитель производит целочисленное значение и помещает его в очередь, **значение не изменяется пока, кто-либо из потребителей не потребит одно или несколько значений со склада. Тогда производитель начинает производство со значения на 1 больше.** Производитель производит значения и помещает их на склад либо пока склад не станет полным, либо **пока его работу не прервет кто-либо из потребителей.** Потребитель потребляет значения со склада либо пока склад не станет пустым, **либо пока его работу не прервет другой потребитель или производитель.**

Я не понимаю как можно реализовать то, что выделено жирным. Если с прерыванием потока еще более менее понимаю, что надо использовать isInterrupted(), и notify(), то с тем, как отлавливать то, что потребитель потребил со склада (то есть вызвал метод get()), я вообще не понимаю...

Вот код склада.

```java
public class Storage implements Queue {

    private int[] arr;
    private int first, last;
    private ReentrantLock locker;
    private Condition condition;


    public Storage() {
        arr = new int[10];
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
        this.locker = new ReentrantLock();
        this.condition = locker.newCondition();
    }

    public void printQueue() {
        try {
            locker.lock();
            if (last > first) {
                for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                }
            } else if (first > last) {
                for (int i = first; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                }
            } else { // 1 элемент
                System.out.println(arr[first]);
            }
        } finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void put(int val) {
        try {
            locker.lock();
            arr[++last] = val;
        } finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int get() {
        try {
            locker.lock();
            int val = arr[last--];
            //  если был 1 элемент в очереди, то передвинем начало и конец в 0
            if (last == first) {
                last = 0;
                first = 0;
            }
            return val;
        } finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }
    }

    /*
    Не использовать при реализации методов full() и empty() условное выражение или оператор ветвления.
     _ _ _ _ _ 2 1 _ _ _ - если first > last и они рядом друг с другом, значит полная
     1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 2 - если просто лежат 10 штук, то last = 9 и first = 0
     */
    @Override
    public boolean full() {
        try {
            locker.lock();
            return (first > last && first - last == 1) || (last > first && last - first == arr.length - 1);
        } finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }
    }

    /*
    Не использовать при реализации методов full() и empty() условное выражение или оператор ветвления.
    поскольку непонятно, как считать пустоту из-за циклической очереди, будем считать, что если last = first = 0,
    то очередь пустая
     */
    @Override
    public boolean empty() {
        try {
            return first == 0 && last == 0;
        } finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

И заготовки производителя и потребителя.

```java
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private Storage storage;
    private Thread thread;
    private int value;
    public Producer(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.value = 1;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!storage.full()){
            storage.put(value);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private Storage storage;
    private Thread thread;
    public Consumer(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!storage.empty()){
            int got = storage.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Буду рад советам.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [SynchronousChannel](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/SynchronousChannel.html) из утилит [Doug Lea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea)

При должной настройке, должен решить вашу задачу.

**Update**

в простом варианте, можно решить вашу задачу семафорами. Если заглянуть под капот `SynchronousChannel`, то там будет что-то типа:

```
public class SynchronousChannel {
    protected Object item = null;
    protected final Semaphore putPermit;
    protected final Semaphore takePermit;
    protected final Semaphore taken;

    public SynchronousChannel() {
        putPermit = new Semaphore(1);
        takePermit = new Semaphore(0);
        taken = new Semaphore(0);
    }

    public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
        putPermit.acquire();
        item = x;
        takePermit.release();


        InterruptedException caught = null;
        for(;;){  //не складываем (не производим), пока не потребится
            try {
                taken.acquire();
                break;
            }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                caught = ie;
            }
        }
        if(caught !=null) throw caught;
    }

    public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
        takePermit.acquire();
        Object x = item;
        item = null;
        putPermit.release(); //разрешаем производство
        taken.release();
        return x;
    }
}
```

Осталось вам здесь немного подрихтовать с шаблонами (внедрить типизацию заготовок) и что-то с емкостью склада. В общем дело техники.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу, так как работа подразумевает использование только основных инструментов для многопоточности.

Comment: посмотрите на апдейт ответа

Comment: Это слишком сложно для меня) я просто использовал костыльную переменную и  вроде работает.

Comment: семафоры почти что то же самое, что и переменные, только *safe-thread*. Но если уж вам так нравится использовать переменные, то хотя бы пометьте их как `volatile`